# Unable to import database to mysql in CentOS 6.3

Tags: mysql, centos

I want to import database file to MySql in Centos 6.3 I entered the following command **mysql -u root -p database < filename.sql** but I faced the error as
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p Kalsym < /tmp/dump.sql' at line 1
I have tried all the commands that I found on various forums but nothing seems to be working here :(

Comment: can you post several lines from the start of your SQL file? seems it is malformed, but we cannot be sure without looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you run this query after login into your MySQL server as it gives sytax error, right?

This command is run from the shell not from the mysql console..

So try running from command prompt/ shell not after login in to the mysql server.

Thanks